# Remove #, and RT from the tweet

Tags: python, twitter

I have millions of tweets and I want to remove `"#"` and `"RT"` from the tweet. For example: `"RT @ABC: Meslekten ihraç edilen #polis müdürü Murat Çetiner"` should give the output `" @ABC: Meslekten ihraç edilen polis müdürü Murat Çetiner"`

Here is the code that I have for now:

```
# coding:utf-8
import sys
x = "RT @zamancomtr: Meslekten ihraç edilen polis müdürü Murat Çetiner: Bana takdir belgesi veren     BM de mi paralel? http://t.co/sd5N6yaZzv http:…"
y = ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",x).split())
print y
```

Comment: So what does that code *do*? What is the problem; what should it be doing instead? What have you tried so far to fix it?

Comment: The code removes all the special characters in the tweet, I want to use regex, but I am not sure on how to use it.

Comment: Then perhaps you should start learning how to use it: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: Can I remove RT using index if so, how can I remove the RT by finding the index position of "," and "@" and then chop off the RT present in between them .. Here is the code :    f = open("clean.txt", "r")
for item in f:
 comma_pos = item.find(",")
 print comma_pos
 at_pos = item.find("@")
 print at_pos

Answer (score 0):

You may use next code:

```
z = lambda x: re.compile('\#').sub('', re.compile('RT @').sub('@', x, count=1).strip())
print z(x)
```

Firstly `re.compile('RT @').sub('@', x, count=1)` replaces first `'RT'` before nickname. If you want to remove any occasion of retweet label in post, just remove `count=1` from code. It is necessary to use mask 'RT @' because 'RT' may occur in tweet body.

As the same, `re.compile('\#')` removes all hashtags from tweet.